# Userspace solution to use store data and create a UDP server

Tags: shell-script, tee, nc

I'm trying to come up with a good way manage an intermittently connected device that I'm using for a research project.   It's a sensor that goes in and out of the water.  While under water, of course, I cannot read the data.  The sensor sends data via UDP to a little linux computer on 192.168.1.2 on port 7954.

```
nc -ul 192.168.1.2 7954 > data.dat
```

The OS is Debian Buster (kernel 4.19) on an ARM.  What I would like to do is also create a "udp server" on port 7777, so if I connect to 192.168.1.2 on port 7777, I will be able to receive some of the data stream just to check on the data that is being written to data.dat.  The reason that I want a server type setup is that there might be two of us connecting to it.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All UDP connections are "one way". What hardware and OS is on the "little linux computer"? What resources are available to solve the problem? Do you have `perl`?

Comment: @waltinator It's debian.  I'll find out the official version and edit the question.

Comment: @waltinator no, it doesn't have perl.  I don't have root on the device.  That was why I was hoping for some sort of shell-based solution.

Comment: **Every** debian system has at least `perl-base` installed as it is tagged `Essential: yes`.   From `perl-base`'s description: "This package provides a Perl interpreter and the small subset of the standard run-time library required to perform basic tasks."

Comment: BTW, udp is connectionless, you send packets and hope they arrive and hope they get received by something listening for them.   your `nc` command may be listening for UDP packets on port 7777 but that doesn't mean that the program you're asking for here should use udp, it sounds more like a classic tcp server.    Also BTW, have you tried something like `ssh user@littlelinuxcomputer tail -f /path/to/data.dat`?